# Aurelia router view animation with swap-order="with"

Tags: aurelia

I am using aurelia-animator-css to animate router views. Upon navigation to a new router view, I want the current view to slide off screen to the left while the new view slides onto the screen from the right.

Here is my router-view element:

`<router-view swap-order="with"></router-view>`

Here is the top element in each of the views:

`<div class="pages au-animate">`

And here is the css:

```
@keyframes slideLeftIn {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideLeftOut {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
.pages.au-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.pages.au-enter-active {
  animation: slideLeftIn 0.6s;
}
.pages.au-leave-active {
  animation: slideLeftOut 0.6s;
}
```

I am using autoprefixer, so there is no need for prefixes such as "webkit-".

With `swap-order="with"`, the current view slides off screen to the left, and then the new view appears without sliding.

The same thing happens with `swap-order="before"`.

Here's a [youtube screen video](https://youtu.be/1rIwOJRbFCU) with `swap-order="with"`.

With `swap-order="after"`, the current view slides off screen to the left, and then the new view slides in from the right.

Here's a [youtube screen video](https://youtu.be/71uFdyckTS4) with `swap-order="after"`.

I would think that `swap-order="with"` would be the one that is needed in this situation. But `swap-order="after"` is closest to what I need, since both views actually perform slides, just not together.

Comment: I changed the .pages.au-enter-active animation duration from 0.6s to 1.6s just to see what happens with swap-order="with". It shows the new view sliding in from the right only after the current view is completely off screen. The new view is partially shown at first and then it slides on in as expected. So it seems that the new view is invisible until the current view is removed from the DOM. So now I'm thinking the issue has something to do with my css, but I'm not sure what it might be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried out a simple project and it works properly, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the other css for .pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to add the following styles to my .pages class:

```
.pages {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: $navBarHeight; /* using sass var for the height of my navbar */
}
```

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: can I ask if you ever managed to reverse the animation when the user hits the back-button, and if so, how?

Comment: @powerbuoy A bit late, but anyway. You could create two new directives where you "invert" the `transform`'s. Then apply a class when navigating backwards so that you use the opposite animations.

Comment: @scheien I have a pretty good idea on how to invert the animation, the problem I'm having is detecting a backwards navigation. More here: https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/436

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is not an answer to the question, but more an addition to the animation style and question from @powerbouy in the accepted answer.*

If anyone came here, as I did, looking for a way to have a phone style navigation:

You would need two more animations, which inverts the direction.

```
@keyframes slideRightIn {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideRightOut {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
}
```

Then you would need a new set of animation classes:

```
.slide-right .pages.au-enter {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
.slide-right .pages.au-enter-active {
  animation: slideRightIn 0.4s;
}
.slide-right .pages.au-leave-active {
  animation: slideRightOut 0.4s;
}
```

To use the left to right backwards navigation style, you would need to apply the `slide-right` class to your an parent element of `.pages`

You could attach it on the `router-view` element in a `back()` method like:

```
  back() {
        document.querySelector('router-view').classList.add('slide-right');
        window.history.back(-1);
  }
```

Then on the `detach()` event, you remove it.

```
detached() {
    // remove class after animation. Only opt-in for showing "back" style animation.
    document.querySelector('router-view').classList.remove('slide-right');
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

To also detect use of the browsers back button, you could tap into the `popstate` event. The `PLATFORM` object comes from the Aurelia PAL package.

Add an eventhandler:

```
backEventHandler = () => { this.back(true); };
```

Add event listener when component is attached:

```
attached() {
        PLATFORM.global.addEventListener("popstate", this.backEventHandler);
    }
```

Remove event listener when component is detached:

```
detached() {
        // remove class after animation. Only opt-in for showing "back" style animation.
        document.querySelector('router-view').classList.remove('slide-right');

        PLATFORM.global.removeEventListener("popstate", this.backEventHandler);
    }
```

Update the `back()` function to also include a parameter to tell if it's called from the browser or not.

```
back(native?: boolean) {
        document.querySelector('router-view').classList.add('slide-right');

        if (!native) {
            window.history.back(-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works fine when using your own `back()` method, but not when the user clicks the back button. I'm looking for a way to detect _all_ types of backwards navigation reliably.

Comment: You could tap into the `popstate` event as mentioned in the github issue.

Comment: Naw, that fires regardless