# Aurelia router animation

Tags: aurelia

I'm using `au-animate` in each view to make a page transition:
the current view slides left out (from center to left) and the next view slides left in (from right to center).

```
@keyframes slideLeftIn {
  0% {transform: translate(100%, 0);}
  100% {transform: translate(0, 0);}
}
@keyframes slideLeftOut {
  0% {transform: translate(0, 0);}
  100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0);}
}
.pages.au-enter-active {
  animation: slideLeftIn 0.8s;
}
.pages.au-leave-active {
  animation: slideLeftOut 0.8s;
}
```

Based on: [Aurelia router view animation with swap-order="with"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102276/aurelia-router-view-animation-with-swap-order-with)

Now, I need to have both views in the DOM during the transition, like in [W3 slide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_trans_slide).

Is there a way to achieve this in [aurelia](http://aurelia.io/)?

UPDATE:

It appears to be a bug preventing this:
[error aurelia-templating-router 1.0.1 with swap-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029542/error-aurelia-templating-router-1-0-1-with-swap-order)

UPDATE2:
In the last release this bug was fixed! Aurelia rocks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@keyframes slideLeftIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
            transform: translate(100%, 0); }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none; } }

@keyframes slideLeftOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none; }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0); } }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, there is a problem when I use `swap-order="with"`. The console log `ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'animatableElement' of undefined` and when I change router it keeps adding views. Essentially there is no animation. But it works with `swap-order="before"` and  `swap-order="after"`, so maybe it's bug. Now I'm using `swap-order="after"` for a similar animation but there is a gap between the views as you know.

Comment: Hmm. `swap-order="with"` is working fine for me. Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: I'm using ES: `au new --here`, `1. Web (Default)`, `1. Babel (Default)`, `3. Sass`. Also `au -v` is 0.23.0.

Comment: Using `swap-order="with"` I see `au-enter au-enter-active` but there is not `au-leave au-leave-active` which is related to the error log, I think. So it keeps adding views to the DOM.

Comment: Aurelia adds the `au-leave` and `au-leave-active` classes when the router is about to change views. Regardless, the views should be removed from the DOM. Are you sure those views are staying in the DOM?

Comment: Pretty sure and I'm not the only one having problems with `swap-order="with"` as you can see from my updated question.